# Handling multiple types of responses from same api using angular HttpClient

Tags: angular

I have a backend api which when called produces html or json responses. The problem here is I don't have control on the response type. I am using angular httpclient module which has optional responseType param that we can use to specify response types. When I try to mention the responseType explicitly as 'html' it works fine for html type of responses, while won't work as expected when response is JSON. 
It worked fine when I used angular http as http by default wont expect the response to be json.

Note: When I don't mention responseType the httpclient throws HttpErrorResponse and this error has the content in it.

I have tried setting responseType: 'text' | 'html' but this results in error: Forbidden bitwise operation (no-bitwise)

This is what I have been doing.

```
let headersForHtmlResponseType: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
            headersForHtmlResponseType = 
headersForHtmlResponseType.set('Accept', 'application/json , 
text/plain');

requiredOptionsForHtmlResponse 
           = {
                headers: headersForHtmlResponseType,
                //responseType: 'text'
            };


return this.httpClient.get(url, requiredOptionsForHtmlResponse);
```

This resulted in HttpErrorResponse as HttpClient cannot parse the html response to JSON. When I remove the comment on resposneType the result is fine for html responses, but it converts the JSON response to text which I don' need.

I want to handle both these response types using HttpClient. Is there any way to stop HttpClient from parsing html content to JSON or JSON content to text?

Comment: Just get the raw body (see the docs) and parse it how you need to, but if the API doesn't respect content type negotiation that's a problem.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Is it controlled by observe property in request options? I changed it to observe: 'response' but still HttpClient is parsing the response and throwing error if the response is html type.

Comment: no, it isn't controlled by that. Setting `responseType: 'text'` doesn't *"parse the JSON to text"*, it just... *doesn't* parse the text to JSON.